# space-between doesn't provide the expected gaps?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want list items to be displayed with equal space in between all the list items. I decided to code the following.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

But this doesn't work, and I don't understand why?

PS: The same thing works if I write `gap: 10px` instead (px value is an example), ie a gap is being added in between the list items. I thought space-between should do the same?

EDIT: Here is the relevant HTML:-

```
<div class="left-links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
<div class="logo">LOGO</div>
<div class="right-links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

1: What `justify-content: space-between;` gives as an output:

[image: 1: What justify-content: space-between; gives as an output]

2: What I want (and also, I get if I use `gap: 10px;` instead:

[image: 2: What I want (and also, I get if I use gap: 10px; instead]

Comment: It'd be easier to understand if you can recreate your actual issue in fiddle here if possible.

Comment: [Demo](https://jsbin.com/kurisomacu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try and set width to your left and right links class as displayed in the snippet below.
Hope that'll help you out

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.left-links {
  width: 40%;
}
.right-links {
  width: 40%;
}
.logo {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="right-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```